# Where are Cancels from Job Queue logged in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I suspect some impatient folks at my place are canceling jobs out of the job queue. The insidious thing about that is that there is no obvious record of the jib having been cancelled, since it didn't even get to run. It just disappears, and if launched as a sub-job, the sub-job simply continues merrily on its way.

How can I check whether someone is canceling stuff in the job queue?

Answer (score 0):

For this information the audit trail plugin of Jenkins seems to be your friend (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Audit+Trail+Plugin).

Answer (score 0):

My answer wouldn't be best but you can try this to find out impatient member in your team and lock him down having access

1. Get the incremental job id(between before and after) and approximate timing which is cancelled/aborted
2. Go to Tomcat/Application server logs and check log record of Logged in details from catalania.out/server.log/....
3. and see the log info says the the job has been cancelled/aborted..

or as other guy said try if the plugin helps you to find out aborted jobs(you can find icon "job config history") under main menu.